# Finding values to fulfil derivative conditions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be defined as follows $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \displaystyle x^2\left(2+\sin\frac 1x \right)& \text{if } 
>  x\neq 0, \\
>                        0 &  \text{if } x=0.
>          \end{cases}$$    For any  $\delta >0$, find a number  $c\in(-\delta,0)$ such that   $f'(c)>0$, and a number
> $d\in(0,\delta)$ such that  $f'(d)<0.$

Having found $f'(x) = 2x\left(2+\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)-\cos\frac{1}{x}$ when $x\neq0$, I am struggling to manipulate the expression to get a suitable value of c and d to fulfil the corresponding conditions. I can't seem to substitute $\sin\frac{1}{x}$ or $\cos\frac{1}{x}$ with known values like I did to solve another question in a similar style that is not shown here. How should I proceed with this question?